# Create delegate with types known at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

How can I create a Delegate with types only known at run time ?

I would like to do the following :

```
Type type1 = someObject.getType();
Type type2 = someOtherObject.getType();   

var getter = (Func<type1, type2>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(
    typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(type1, type2), someMethodInfo);
```

How can I achieve something similar ?

Comment: You can't. `Func<type1, type2 >` is not known at compile time.

Comment: Your variable `getter` will have to have a _compile-time_ type that is known at compile time. That could be `System.Delegate`.

Answer (score 8):

I suspect you want [`Expression.GetFuncType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.getfunctype.aspx) as a simpler way of doing your `typeof(...).MakeGenericType` operation.

```
var delegateType = Expression.GetFuncType(type1, type2);
Delegate getter = Delegate.CreateDelegate(delegateType, someMethodInfo);
```

You can't have a *compile-time* type for `getter` that's more specific than `Delegate` though<sup>1</sup>, because you simply don't know that type at compile-time. You could potentially use `dynamic` though, which would make it easier to invoke the delegate:

```
dynamic getter = ...;
var result = getter(input);
```

---

<sup>1</sup> As noted in comments, you *could* cast to `MulticastDelegate`, but it wouldn't actually buy you anything.

Comment: +1: sicophantic upvote from me without reading the question nor answer. Doing my duty! (kidding)

Comment: `MulticastDelegate` is more specific ;p

Answer (score 3):

You could create a generic method for that:

```
public Func<T1, T2> GetFunc<T1, T2>(T1 Object1, T2 Object2, MethodInfo Method)
{
    return (Func<T1, T2>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T1), typeof(T2)), Method);
}
```

And I bet you can do something using the same philosophy with the Method to avoid all this reflection stuff.

Obs: that would work only if T1 and T2 are typed variables. If they are `as object` you'll get a `Func<object, object>`. But....if the objects you will give to the method are `as object` as well, that would be no problem at all.
And maybe you can even use `Func<object, object>` always, depending on your scenario.