# In c# can you dynamically load an unmanaged DLL and also dynamically specify the function call?

Tags: c#, dll, unmanaged

I need to dynamically load an unmanaged DLL and dynamically specify the function calls and parameters. In examples I found you and methods I used in the past you statically specify the delegate in the top of the class. I am not sure this is even possible.

The following is and example of static delegate part, but also has the non working dynamically defined delegate also.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
  //Declare the delegate to represent the function signature I want to do this dynamically
  [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
  private delegate int MyFunctionDelegate(int a, int b);

  static void Main()
  {
    try
    {
      //Change path to dll
      string dllPath = @"C:\Projects_VS\Tests\DynamicLoadDLLTest\simpleCDLL.dll";
      //function name to call
      string functionName = "Add";

      if (!File.Exists(dllPath))
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Missing DLL file.");
      }

      // Dynamically load the user-specified DLL
      IntPtr dllHandle = LoadLibrary(dllPath);

      if (dllHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to load the DLL.");
        return;
      }


      // Get the function address from the loaded DLL
      IntPtr functionAddress = GetProcAddress(dllHandle, functionName);
      if (functionAddress == IntPtr.Zero)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to get the function address.");
        return;
      }

      // Currently works
      MyFunctionDelegate myFunction = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer<MyFunctionDelegate>(functionAddress);
      int result = myFunction(10, 20);

      //What I want to do 
      IntPtr functionPtr = GetProcAddress(dllHandle, "Add");
      delegate int DynamicFunctionDelegate(int parameter1, int parameter2); 
      DynamicFunctionDelegate myFunction = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer<DynamicFunctionDelegate>(functionPtr);
      int result = myFunction(10, 20);

      Console.WriteLine("Result: " + result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + ex.Message);
    }
  }

  // Helper method to dynamically load the DLL
  [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
  private static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad);

  // Helper method to get the function address from the loaded DLL
  [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
  private static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procedureName);
}
```

Update - I found a different example (http://netcode.ru/dotnet/?lang=&katID=30&skatID=264&artID=7243) and modified it but it isn't calling the DLL. Is this a valid path to follow?

```
static void Main()
{
  //Change path to dll
  string dllPath = @"E:\Projects_VS\Tests\DynamicLoadDLLTest\SimpleCDLL.dll";
  //function name to call
  string functionName = "Add";
  object[] parameterValues = { 5, 10 };

  object r = DynamicDllFunctionInvoke(dllPath, functionName, parameterValues);

}


public static object DynamicDllFunctionInvoke(string DllPath, string entrypoint, object[] funcPrams)
{
  //Define return type of your dll function.
  Type returnType = typeof(int);
  //out or in parameters of your function.
  int n = funcPrams.Length;
  Type[] parameterTypes = new Type[n];
  for (int i =0; i<n; ++i)
  {
    parameterTypes[i] = funcPrams[i].GetType();
  }
  string entryPoint = entrypoint;

  // Create a dynamic assembly and a dynamic module
  AssemblyName asmName = new AssemblyName();
  asmName.Name = "tempDll";
  AssemblyBuilder dynamicAsm = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(asmName,
          AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
  ModuleBuilder dynamicMod =
    dynamicAsm.DefineDynamicModule("tempModule");

  // Dynamically construct a global PInvoke signature 
  // using the input information
  MethodBuilder dynamicMethod = dynamicMod.DefinePInvokeMethod(
    entryPoint, DllPath, MethodAttributes.Static | MethodAttributes.Public
    | MethodAttributes.PinvokeImpl, CallingConventions.Standard,
    returnType, parameterTypes, CallingConvention.Winapi,
    CharSet.Ansi);

  // This global method is now complete
  dynamicMod.CreateGlobalFunctions();

  // Get a MethodInfo for the PInvoke method
  MethodInfo mi = dynamicMod.GetMethod(entrypoint);
  // Invoke the static method and return whatever it returns
  object retval = mi.Invoke(null, funcPrams);

  return retval;
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify exactly what dynamic capabilities do you need? Do you want to define the parameter list, types and return value type at runtime without knowing it at the compile time? Or do you just want to move the delegate declaration to the function level?

Comment: I want to define the define the function call, parameter list, types and return value. I just got stuck at this point so didn't go any further.

Comment: If everything is dynamic how do you propose to call the function if you don't know what parameters it wants?

Comment: You can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16484092/create-delegate-with-types-known-at-runtime and this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.getdelegatetype?view=net-7.0 about how to create delegate type at runtime. Then use `Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer` with this new type (you will need a lot of reflection).

Comment: This is for modeling and simulation, The user will specify a dll, call, and parameters in order to get get a value back. They know the DLL and call to use, not me.

Comment: @Serg - I tried that, but can't figure out how to get get the "MethodInfo" and link it to the dll call.

Comment: It's not enough just to use reflection to invoke an unmanaged delegate. The problem is that PInvoke is almost impossible to do without predefining what marshalling you want. For example, if the user passes a string, do you want to pass that as `LPStr` `LPWStr` `BStr` or `ByValTStr`?